# Problem with jQuery Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lightbox, colorbox

I have a website that uses ajax jquery and colorbox.

Inside the div "#content" there are some links to other pages that open fine using colorbox.

If I reload the content of that div using ajax jquery , then the links wont popup using colorbox effect anymore.

I tried to create a function that I would call whenever I call the function that changes the contents of div #content , but no luck . I know that I must reinit/reload the colorbox to DOM everytime I load something new to the page that contains rel="colorbox" ,but I cant figure it out how.I call this inside

```
function showcategory() {
reinit();
...
}

function reinit() {
  $('a[rel*=colorbox]').colorbox() ;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801058/colorbox-and-content-returned-via-ajax/4801336#4801336 -- here the find method does the job..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to attach your handler using `live` instead of `bind`. This survives content-reloads in the divs

the api doc for live is [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method or `delegate` method for dynamic generated content events.