# Colorbox and Content returned via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using jquery colorbox to popup user accounts in a window. I also have a button that loads more users into the page via ajax, but for some reason users loaded with ajax do not popup in colorbox window. How can I get colorbox to work with the content that was returned via ajax?

```
function loadMore(pageNo) {
    //$("#loading").html('Loading...').show();
    var url = '/search/resultsAjax';
    $.get(url, {page: pageNo}, function(response) {
        $("#results").append(response);
        //$("#loading").hide();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var currPage = 1;
    $("a.next").click(function() {
        loadMore(++currPage);
    });

    $("a.usr").colorbox({width:"960px", height:"90%", iframe:true});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you bind colorbox in `$(document).ready()` with this:

```
$("a.usr").colorbox({width:"960px", height:"90%", iframe:true});
```

jQuery will go search through the page, grab everything that matches `a.usr`, bind colorbox to those items, and then forget all about `a.usr`. jQuery won't remember that you're interested in `a.usr` so the new ones won't be colorbox'd.

The usual solution to this sort of thing is to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` but those won't work here as there isn't a "colorbox" event.

However, you can bind colorbox by hand easily enough. Try change `loadMore` to something more like this:

```
function loadMore(pageNo) {
    $.get('/search/resultsAjax', { page: pageNo }, function(response) {
        var $html = $(response);
        $html.find('a.usr').colorbox({ width: '960px', height: '90%', iframe: true });
        $('#results').append($html);
    };
}
```

You just turn the `response` HTML into a jQuery object, find all the `a.usr` things inside it, bind colorbox to those, and then insert the new HTML into the DOM as usual.

Comment: thank you for response, I was just wondering, would there be any difference, if I appended html first and then re-bind colorbox?

Comment: @BugBusterX: You might end up binding colorbox to the same element twice and that could cause some confusion and bizarre behavior. Colorbox might be able to handle double binding but I wouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make it work globally, regardless of how the content is loaded:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.usr', function() {
    $(this).colorbox({width:"960px", height:"90%", iframe:true});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<a onclick='parent.$.colorbox({href:"schedule_delete.php?sid=<?php echo $schedule_row->schedule_id; ?>"}); return false;'>delete</a
```